# Installing Mongoose in NodeJS 0.10.8

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have node 0.10.8 installed in Ubuntu machine.

I tried to install mongoose:

```
npm install mongoose
```

But got the following message in terminal:

```
> kerberos@0.0.2 install /___/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

> bson@0.1.8 install /___/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

Whats this error?

Comment: Does the install stop after that? If so, check out the contents of the file `/___/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/builderror.log`, it should contain more information.

Comment: the `buildererror.log` just contain 2 lines: `gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.8/node-v0.10.8.tar.gz`
`gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.8/node-v0.10.8.tar.gz`

Comment: Sounds like it installed just fine then :)

Comment: I got the same problem. Is moongose installed success or failed? I'm scare with some thing hanged like this

Comment: the installation was successful though

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually an error. If you check the `builderror.log` files in the bson and kerberos module folders, you'll see that the logs are empty. Try spooling up your MongoDB server instance and launch your Node.JS app. If you have any more error feedback, please post as an edit and I will add more information.

I had the same exact issue. [Here is a link to my StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768082/npm-install-mongoose-fails-kerberos-and-bson-errors).