# npm install mongoose on Joyent's smartOS machine

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I tried to install mongoose on my Joyent's SmartOS machine and got error messages. I know for sure I got 2 problems: kerberos and bson. What should I do. Thanks!

*I found this post: [Installing Mongoose in NodeJS 0.10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161680/installing-mongoose-in-nodejs-0-10-8). It does not answer my problem.*

```
/home/node# node -v
v0.10.24
/home/node# mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
/home/node# npm cache clean
/home/node# npm install mongoose
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
        (I assume every alright here)
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/-/kerberos-0.0.3.tgz

> kerberos@0.0.3 install /home/node/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> bson@0.2.5 install /home/node/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

mongoose@3.8.8 node_modules/mongoose


/home/node# more node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/builderror.log
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/whic
h.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/whic
h.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.j
s:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System SunOS 5.11
gyp ERR! command "node" "/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/b
in/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/node/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/
bson
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
/home/node#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with Joyent's support and their respond was insufficiency of memory may cause these errors.