# npm install mongoose fails (kerberos and bson errors)

Tags: mongoose, npm, kerberos, bson, node-gyp

So I'm attempting to launch my node app, but there's a few errors arising from my MongoDB installation.

*Here are the specs for my dev environment:*

**node => 0.10.33** (installed from nodejs.org)

**npm => 1.4.28** (installed from nodejs.org)

**git => 2.1.3** (homebrewed)

**mongodb => 2.6.5** (homebrewed)

If it makes a difference, I am also using the [Mean Stack Skeleton](https://github.com/vkarpov15/mean-stack-skeleton) as part of a tutorial.

In a nutshell, when I try to run my node app using `$ node app.js`, I get the following feedback:

```
USER$ npm install mongoose

> kerberos@0.0.4 install /Users/USER/APP/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node: Finished

> bson@0.2.15 install /Users/USER/APP/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node: Finished
mongoose@3.8.18 node_modules/mongoose
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── muri@0.3.1
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── hooks@0.2.1
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── mpromise@0.4.3
├── ms@0.1.0
├── mquery@0.8.0 (debug@0.7.4)
└── mongodb@1.4.12 (readable-stream@1.0.33, kerberos@0.0.4, bson@0.2.15)
```

I checked the `builderror.log` files for both the `kerberos` and `bson` modules. However, both are empty.

Some research I have found suggests that the issue might be because my `node-gyp` installation does not have a corresponding `binding.gyp` file.

Also tried running `$ node-gyp configure` inside my Node.js project folder. And this is the error I received:

```
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/USER/APP) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/USER/APP
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Any ideas why I am having these issues?

EDIT: After setting the port in my `app.js` file to set the port to the same one that the Express server is listening on (duh), I get more feedback indicating that I was using Mongoose 3.9.4, which is the latest unstable release of `mongoose`. So I set the module to 3.8.18 in my `package.json` and attempted to reinstall the module. I received the same errors. However, the unstable release feedback is gone now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I `cd`'d into the `kerberos` and `bson` directories, I used the command `$ node-gyp rebuild` and the node modules compiled correctly.

My `app.js` file, I called the following lines:

```
var app = express();
...
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = Mongoose.createConnection('localhost','database');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

This port number must be unique from the port of your database instance.

In a separate terminal window, run `$ mongod` to spool up your MongoDB. Once it's called, in yet another terminal window, you call `$ mongo database`. This creates the database instance called `database` for your Node.js app to connect to. In your original terminal window, call `$ node app.js` and it will run without any error feedback.

The errors I was getting were not the result of an incorrect build of Mongoose, MongoDB or any of their dependencies. The errors were a result of a misconception about MongoDB. MongoDB must be running as a process separate to your Node.js app in order for the app to make a database connection.

Answer (score 54):

For anyone on a Linux distro ensure you have `libkrb5-dev` (or your distro's similar package) installed.  This will take care of many build errors with bson and kerberos.

Comment: Thank you very much , it works! I had the same problem in Linux Mint 17 and resolved to install the package : http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libkrb5-dev

Comment: Managed to install Mongoose and MongoDB this using this tip. I still had a few warnings in my terminal but no errors. Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: In centOS [(from docs, I think?)](http://download.sinenomine.net/openafs/projects/build-tools/doc/kerberos-5-setup.txt): `yum install krb5-server krb5-workstation krb5-libs krb5-devel`

Comment: in Alpine, if anyone is doing this in a docker image, the package is `krb5-dev` did the trick.

Answer (score 18):

For ubuntu users, first uninstall moongose

```
npm uninstall mongoose --save
```

then install the a kerberos update

```
apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```

then "install" moongose again

```
npm install mongoose --save
```

I hope this helps somebody there.

Answer (score 14):

I've fixed this by installing node-gyp into the global scope. Hope it helps.

```
$ npm install -g node-gyp
```

Answer (score 4):

I just uninstall mongodb and then install mongoose successfully.

```
npm uninstall mongodb --save
npm install mongoose --save
```